# Python - номерованние файла +i

Tags: python

Есть глобальный timestamp

```
ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Пытаюсь написать следующие, при нажатии на кнопку, создается один скриншот

```
@app.route("/screenshot", methods=['POST'])
def screenshot():
    # Переменную не меняем — global необязателен
    with camlock:
        if not camera:
            return 'Camera is not started'
    for i in range(1):
        camera.capture('%d-image-%s.jpeg' % (+i, st), use_video_port=True)
    return 'Saved to %d-image-%s.jpeg' % (+i, st)
```

В моем случае, прибавляется в начале название файла `0` и все. Где я ошибся? Знаю что в Python нету `++i`

Comment: А что, по Вашему мнению, должно прибавиться? Т.к. i=0, +i тоже, очевидно, равно 0.

Comment: @andy.37 тогда как к этом i = 0, прибавить после каждого вызова +1?

Comment: i+1, нет разве? `'%d-image-%s.jpeg' % (i+1, st)`

Comment: @andy.37 к сожалению тоже нет

Comment: Тогда просто непонятно, что Вы хотите получить.

Comment: @andy.37 Вы правильно поняли, что к %d (i) должно добавляется +1; но i+1 не работает - то есть, один раз нажали 1-image-2016-02-09 13:01:47.jpeg, второй раз 2-image-2016-02-09 13:01:47.jpeg; сейчас же при каждом нажатии 1-image-2016-02-09 13:01:47.jpeg

Comment: Оффтоп: если код базируется на моём ответе из другого вопроса, то нельзя использовать `camera` вне блока `with camlock` — в один прекрасный день всё может внезапно взять и заглючить непредсказуемым образом из-за возможной потоконебезопасности

Comment: @andreymal то есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен аналог статической переменной, которой нет в питоне. Смотрите тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function

как вариант:

```
@app.route("/screenshot", methods=['POST'])
def screenshot():
    # Переменную не меняем — global необязателен
    screenshot.counter += 1
    with camlock:
        if not camera:
            return 'Camera is not started'
    camera.capture('%d-image-%s.jpeg' % (screenshot.counter, st), use_video_port=True)
    return 'Saved to %d-image-%s.jpeg' % (screenshot.counter, st)
screenshot.counter = 0
```

Если это не сработает в flask - используйте варианты с декораторами по ссылке.

П.С. последняя строчка - именно вне определения функции screenshot.

Comment: если я правильно понял, то вот так? http://pastebin.com/VUCtSQZm

Comment: Все работает как я в писал в pastebin

Comment: ОК, с декоратором и выглядит симпатичней.

Comment: Как минимум понятнее)